# How to add new custom fields to already existing reports and dashboards in bulk

Tags: reporting, custom-field, fields, dashboard, bulk

I was just wondering if there is a way of adding a couple of (new) custom fields to already existing reports IN BULK instead of manually selecting (each report) to then add my new custom fields in them...

I have 2 new custom fields that need to be added to 50+ reports!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, while creating a new field, salesforce does not provide an option to link that field with reports.

We need to manually add that field as a column in all the reports.